# Issue in CAS 4.1.3 SLO

Tags: java, single-sign-on, logout, cas

Im trying to impl SLO in casified application (cas client core 3.4.1)

Created 3 instances of cas-sample-java-webapp-master from [cas-sample-java-webapp](https://github.com/cas-projects/cas-sample-java-webapp)
After logging into all 3 apps, 
Im logging out of client1 > this logs out client1 and cas.
but client2 and client3 is logged in.
Not sure what I have missed

Added CAS Single Sign Out Filter in clients **web.xml**

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>https://localhost:8443/cas</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Following were the logs related to client2 and client3, while logging out client1

```
11:50:43,098 DEBUG [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (pool-13-thread-3) Secure session established
11:50:43,098 DEBUG [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (pool-13-thread-3)  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
11:50:43,098 DEBUG [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (pool-13-thread-3)  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
11:50:43,098 DEBUG [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (pool-13-thread-3)  peer principal: CN=localhost
11:50:43,098 DEBUG [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (pool-13-thread-3)  issuer principal: CN=localhost
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] (pool-13-thread-3) Connection established <my_ip>:55307<-><my_ip>:8443
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (pool-13-thread-3) Executing request POST /client2 HTTP/1.1
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (pool-13-thread-3) Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (pool-13-thread-3) Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> POST /client2 HTTP/1.1
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 484
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> Host: localhost:8443
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.8.0_92)
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /client2 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 484[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localhost:8443[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.8.0_92)[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,101 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 >> "logoutRequest=%3Csamlp%3ALogoutRequest+xmlns%3Asamlp%3D%22urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Aprotocol%22+ID%3D%22LR-3-QEo4g9q44zCinXYJGKuJ7v6WNzwo6WC4csW%22+Version%3D%222.0%22+IssueInstant%3D%222018-05-20T11%3A50%3A42Z%22%3E%3Csaml%3ANameID+xmlns%3Asaml%3D%22urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Aassertion%22%3E%40NOT_USED%40%3C%2Fsaml%3ANameID%3E%3Csamlp%3ASessionIndex%3EST-2-UdNRzkc6qZLihn3Uc6Az-cas01.example.org%3C%2Fsamlp%3ASessionIndex%3E%3C%2Fsamlp%3ALogoutRequest%3E"
11:50:43,106 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,106 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,106 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << "X-Powered-By: MY-APP-SERVER[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,106 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << "Server: MY-APP-SERVER[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,106 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << "Location: https://localhost:8443/client2/[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,106 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,106 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Sun, 20 May 2018 06:20:43 GMT[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,108 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,108 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
11:50:43,108 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << Connection: keep-alive
11:50:43,108 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << X-Powered-By: MY-APP-SERVER
11:50:43,108 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << Server: MY-APP-SERVER
11:50:43,108 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << Location: https://localhost:8443/client2/
11:50:43,108 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 0
11:50:43,108 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-3) http-outgoing-0 << Date: Sun, 20 May 2018 06:20:43 GMT
11:50:43,108 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (pool-13-thread-3) Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
11:50:43,108 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] (pool-13-thread-3) Connection [id: 0][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443] can be kept alive indefinitely
11:50:43,108 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] (pool-13-thread-3) Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443][total kept alive: 2; route allocated: 3 of 50; total allocated: 3 of 100]
11:50:43,113 DEBUG [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (pool-13-thread-1) Secure session established
11:50:43,113 DEBUG [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (pool-13-thread-1)  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
11:50:43,113 DEBUG [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (pool-13-thread-1)  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
11:50:43,113 DEBUG [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (pool-13-thread-1)  peer principal: CN=localhost
11:50:43,113 DEBUG [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (pool-13-thread-1)  issuer principal: CN=localhost
11:50:43,113 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] (pool-13-thread-1) Connection established <my_ip>:55308<-><my_ip>:8443
11:50:43,113 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (pool-13-thread-1) Executing request POST /client3 HTTP/1.1
11:50:43,113 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (pool-13-thread-1) Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
11:50:43,113 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (pool-13-thread-1) Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
11:50:43,113 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> POST /client3 HTTP/1.1
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> Content-Length: 484
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> Host: localhost:8443
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.8.0_92)
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> "POST /client3 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Length: 484[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> "Host: localhost:8443[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.8.0_92)[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,116 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 >> "logoutRequest=%3Csamlp%3ALogoutRequest+xmlns%3Asamlp%3D%22urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Aprotocol%22+ID%3D%22LR-1-audt9vCEwA6SOHXNgA4BfdHgWySeTs62Edi%22+Version%3D%222.0%22+IssueInstant%3D%222018-05-20T11%3A50%3A42Z%22%3E%3Csaml%3ANameID+xmlns%3Asaml%3D%22urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Aassertion%22%3E%40NOT_USED%40%3C%2Fsaml%3ANameID%3E%3Csamlp%3ASessionIndex%3EST-3-gxiaEaiKCh353tFc6iK1-cas01.example.org%3C%2Fsamlp%3ASessionIndex%3E%3C%2Fsamlp%3ALogoutRequest%3E"
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << "HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << "X-Powered-By: MY-APP-SERVER[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << "Server: MY-APP-SERVER[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << "Location: https://localhost:8443/client3/[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << "Date: Sun, 20 May 2018 06:20:43 GMT[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << "[\r][\n]"
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << Connection: keep-alive
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << X-Powered-By: MY-APP-SERVER
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << Server: MY-APP-SERVER
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << Location: https://localhost:8443/client3/
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << Content-Length: 0
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] (pool-13-thread-1) http-outgoing-2 << Date: Sun, 20 May 2018 06:20:43 GMT
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (pool-13-thread-1) Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] (pool-13-thread-1) Connection [id: 2][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443] can be kept alive indefinitely
11:50:43,118 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] (pool-13-thread-1) Connection released: [id: 2][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443][total kept alive: 3; route allocated: 3 of 50; total allocated: 3 of 100]
11:50:43,133 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.io] (default I/O-8) UT005013: An IOException occurred: java.io.IOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
    at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.notifyReadClosed(SslConduit.java:612)
    at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.doUnwrap(SslConduit.java:708)
    at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.read(SslConduit.java:565)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:153)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:131)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:57)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$SslReadReadyHandler.readReady(SslConduit.java:1122)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:567)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.closeInbound(SSLEngineImpl.java:1561) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_92]
    at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.notifyReadClosed(SslConduit.java:610)
    ... 11 more
```

2 logoutRequest is generated in logs, dont think the requests are reaching signout filters of clients
Also the kestore configs are already done, No idea why SSLException is thrown.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working! 
It was indeed an application configuration error, I was missing a '/' (slash) at the end of client2's URL on web.xml.
I'm not sure it that's expected behavior or not, probably single sign out filter's url pattern was pointing towards that direction.